# shopping cart item price turns zero when "checkout/cart/" page is viewed in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

The price in the shopping cart turns zero when "checkout/cart/" page is viewed. It worked fine before. This issue occurs suddenly without any change/update.
[image: Shopping cart with zero price.]
It showing the correct price in product list and minicart, it turns zero only when "checkout/cart/", "Login"  is clicked.

The $_item->getCalculationPrice() in "checkout/cart/item/default.phtml" file generates zero value.

I m totally blank and don't know where to trace.

Please help me to trace and fix this issue..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved.

Actually after disabling the third party search module js, the price works fine. Some script has override the price value. So it doesn't work. Now it is ok.

I hope this Answer may be useful to some person.

Thank you